# Convert Excel to byte array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, byte, converters

I need to convert file of Excel to byte array in javascript?
I found 
[1 convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926504/how-can-i-read-a-binary-file-with-in-javascript-cscript-exe)

and
[2 convertion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17825/Reading-and-Writing-Binary-Files-Using-JScript)

However, my file is two times smaller after that (oryginal size: 26 624, byte array.length 13 312)
Maybe somehow this method normally works but there is no documentation `ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");` 
Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332002/how-to-store-a-byte-array-in-javascript

Comment: _"but there is no documentation `ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")`"_ - sure there is, at [various](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx) MSDN [pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx).